# Multi Lingual Entities Mapping

Tags: c#, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

```
public class Product : Entity, IMultiLingualEntity
{
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int Stock { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}


public class ProductTranslation : Entity, IEntityTranslation
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Core { get; set; }
    public virtual int CoreId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Language { get; set; }
}
```

for Dto

```
public class ProductCreateDto
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

how can i map ProductCreateDto => Product so that, for new entry a new record for ProductTranslation is inserted with currently language `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name` and for ProductTranslation.Name= ProductCreateDto.Name

Comment: If Product.Translations is a collection and has multiple items in how do we know which `ProductTranslation.Name` to use for `ProductCreateDto.Name`

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Lingual-Entities using CreateMultiLingualMap extension method, only one record from Translations collection of a Multi-Lingual entity will be mapped to target Dto class. This extension method finds the translation with selected UI language first. If there is no translation with selected UI language, then extension method searches for the default language setting and uses the translation in default language. If extension method couldn't find any translation in current UI language or default language, it uses one of the existing translations